# Android custum listview layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am struggling to get my custom listview row layout to handle differing image sizes whilst keeping its overall shape correct.

I want to achieve the following Listview row with differing images of differing sizes. Each row should be of identical size by scaling its images to a specific size.

My desired row layout
[image]

My code (note i have tried several different methods but all either don't scale correctly (ie one image bigger than the other when it shouldn't be) or they dont' stay in correct position relative to one another.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/logo1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/league_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What this yeilds is several prpoblems, spaces around each imagview or textview and not scaling to same size as designed in the xml layout...
[image]

Comment: Why dont you use RelativeLayout as root layout? Also is that the entire layout file or part of it?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to use linear layouts to keep everything rigid. This is the entire layout file for the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/logo1" android:layout_weight="3"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/league_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_image3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Closer but the images are all diff sizes to each other and the all have lots of space around them instead of being closer together. Any idea how i can get each to the 3 images under the text to be the same size and the large image on left hand side to be flush with the top and bottom of the row layout?

Comment: i added a android:weightSum="3" to the second LinearLayout..it should work

Comment: Nope. Its even worse when i view it on the phone. The text is at the top in its correct pos, the logo is half way down the screen and the 3 images are below that. everything is correctly laid out horizontally but the logo and 3 images are diff sizes to each other (ie maintainng their original size maybe??) are at diff vertical positions

Comment: did you add the android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="10" to the 'root' LinearLayout?

Comment: I just realized that i had transparent spaces around my images, the images which i thought Android ignored. I trimmed them with a rudimentary tool and then resized them to 50x50px. I have one more question - how can i make a big image fit into a 50x50 space. I ask as when i re-sized i lost lots of detail that my phone can display at that size.

Comment: that explains ;-) for that you can use one of the ScaleType: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 2):

I used RelativeLayout and following is the solution. **You will have to edit the xml little bit** as I used background colors. Anyways, check whether this works; if not I will start looking into LinearLayout solution:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
android:layout_width="128dp"
android:layout_height="128dp"
android:background="@color/blue" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_logo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/red"

>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/league_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/black"
     >
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/yellow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/green" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this..xml code given by araut works just fine..but still you'll need some adjustments needed to be made accordingly for the row layout to be specific..

Comment: Excellent, this worked once i realized that my images had large transparent spaces around them and i thought Android ignored the transparency. I tweaked and standardized the sizes. Now one more question - if i want an image to fit a space how do i do that? I want my images to remain sharp so il keep them relatively big but i want android to fit them into 50x50dp

Comment: I jsut manually set the sizes by dp. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Cool. Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```